# Not able to get unobfuscated and human-readable stack traces of react native app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I was trying to generate unobfuscated and human-readable stack traces of react native android app.

But I am not able to get unobfuscated stack trace(as checked on firebase crashlytics).

I made following changes to my proguard-rules.pro file.
Added these lines
`-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable        # Keep file names and line numbers. -keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception  # Optional: Keep custom exceptions.` 
in build.gradle, I added this.
    `buildTypes { debug { firebaseCrashlytics { mappingFileUploadEnabled true } } }`

My expectation is to get file names and line numbers in stack trace.

[image: Screenshot of stacktrace from firebase crashlytics dashboard]

[I was following this firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android)

Comment: How are you obfuscating the code? Is it only using Proguard (or similar)? Or is the javascript code being obfuscated?

Comment: @Gerardo Yes, it is the javascript code that is being obfuscated.

Comment: I'm not sure this scenario is supported by Crashlytics. Crashlytics will obtain the mapping files generated by Proguard, r8 or similar but doesn't have access to the mapping files of the Javascript code base.

Answer (score 0):

Just installing crashlytics is not enough for react-native in order to get sensible error logging. In order to achieve sensible errors you also need to send a js error stack trace, you can use - https://github.com/a7ul/react-native-exception-handler .

```
import {setJSExceptionHandler} from 'react-native-exception-handler';

setJSExceptionHandler((error, isFatal) => {
  if(isFatal)
  {
  crashlytics().recordError(new Error(error));
  }
});
```